# Saros login : 'SASL authentication DIGEST-MD5 failed'

Tags: java, eclipse

Me and my friend have been using Saros for a while. But now he bought a new PC and had to download Eclipse and install Saros again.
  The problem is that he is getting this message when trying to log in his account:

Error (SASL authentication DIGEST-MD5 failed: non-authorized)

1) He tried creating another account
2) He tried to copy my eclipse and log in my account

It seems to be a problem with the XMPP connection... is there any way we can solve this problem?
Please we need to know how to solve this issue quickly.

Comment: What Java versions/OS/Eclipse versions are you running?

Comment: [windows7], [eclipse 3.7 or 3.7.1 (we tried both versions)], [JRE 7]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and solved it as follows:

1. Create your account on: https://saros-con.imp.fu-berlin.de:5280/register/new
2. Intall saros on Eclipse : **Installation Steps -> Via Update Site** https://www.saros-project.org/documentation/installation.html
3. Restart Eclipse
4. Click on Saros in navigation bar and [add account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPkU6.png)
5. Enter name before the "@" and enter your password [name/password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRWhv.png)